# IN Query by using List of Object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails , I try to make a Query lets suppose.

Table1(id,subjectId)
Table2(id,subjectId)

Now I have list of Table2 Object in a Object. And now I want to find all those objects from Table1 whose subject id in matches in List of table2 Object . Something like IN Query of Postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start reading the [ActiveRecord Query guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

```
Table1.where("subject_id IN (?)", Table2.all.pluck(:subject_id))
```

You can also pass an array and ActiveRecord will use an `IN` for you.

```
Table1.where(subject_id: Table2.all.pluck(:subject_id))
```

You can also use a JOIN, which is more appropriate as it will use a single query.

Comment: Can you please help me make query using join . Right now     employee=Employee.where(user_id:current_user.id).first , 
  @teacher=Teacher.where(employee_id:employee.id),   @teacherChapter=LessonPlanStatus.where(subject_id:@teacher.map(&:subject_id))

Comment: How familiar are you with the SQL join? You may start from here http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thanks for the link , I am from NoSql , but due to free lancing I took project of Postgres .Could you please help me its urgent

Comment: The query I posted above will work (with the price of two queries instead of one). If you want to use a JOIN, I encourage you to first learn some SQL. It doesn't matter you used NoSQL so far, if you work on the web you'll have to  get familiar with SQL at some point. How to create the join depends on your model configuration.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

I used `LessonPlanStatus.where(subject_id:@teacher.map(&:subject_id))`

Comment: This query is very inefficient because it will load all the teacher objects entirely, then will loop over them. You should use `pluck`.